# Prevent garbage collection inside another window (from post message)

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, window.open

So I've read a bit about object allocation. Feel free to wrong me on this but, when you have an object allocated and have a reference to it, it should not be deleted right?.

Objective: Lets say I used the message channel to get a list and each item on the list was a item with whats below using the window.open method and then sending the post message 24 times a second:

```
{
texture:{index:randomNumber,width:randomNumber,height:randomNumber},
transform: {x:randomNumber,y:randomNumber,rotation:randomNumber0-360}
}
```

Both on the main thread and on the child thread there is a lsit of these objects, and both are currently being cleared after they are done using the objects within. Is there any way that I can create an object pool to make sure that garbage collection does not happen?. - End of Objective statement

this is the code inside the window that I am currently using  to be using to render my objects

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>game</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id= "wrapper" class ="wrapper">
    <canvas  id="canvas" width="3840" height="2160" draggable="true"></canvas>
</div>


<style>


    .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper   canvas {
        position: absolute;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 1000px;
        height: auto;

    }

    .GUI{
        top: -315px;
        left: -302px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: cadetblue;
        opacity: .5;
        word-wrap: break-word;

    }

    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }


</style>

<div id = GUI class = "GUI"></div>
<script src="../HTML-Thread/ImageResource.js"></script>
<script src="../HTML-Thread/background.js"></script>
<script src="../myapi/utils.js"></script>
<script src ="../HTML-Thread/GUI/GUI-functionBox.js"></script>
<script src="../HTML-Thread/GUI/GUI-Control.js"></script>
<script src=" ../HTML-Thread/GUI/PlanetUiCode.js"></script>
<script src="../HTML-Thread/GUI/GameObjectUiCode.js"></script>
<script src = "../myapi/indexedDB/IDBfunctions.js"></script>
<script src ="../HTML-Thread/mainThreadFunctions.js"></script>
<script src="../myapi/engine/BaseVCharacter.js"></script>
<script src="../myapi/engine/BaseGameObject.js"></script>
<script src="../myapi/indexedDB/IDBfunctions.js"></script>
<script src="../myapi/indexedDB/IDBMain.js"></script>




<script>

    window.document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d").canvas.addEventListener("click",onClick);


window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  window.opener.postMessage({Procedure:"onClose",guiOwnerCode:window.guiOwner.guiOwnerCode})
};
    //TODO: Create canvas/canvases here instead of third.html

    window.imageArray = [];
    var cameraFocus = {x:0,y:0,rotation:0}
        ,mapWidth = 10000000,mapHeight = 10000000,
        imageIndexArray = [], myImageResource = new ImageResource(),objectPool = [];

        myImageResource.loadAllTextures(function () {onImagesLoaded();});



    function onImagesLoaded () {
        //when images are loaded build a conversion for images via 'buildImageArray', send message to main js thread to start
        buildImageArray(myImageResource,window.imageArray,imageIndexArray);



    let canvasCtx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

            window.renderScale = .09;
window.guiOwner = {transform:{x:0,y:0,rotation:0}};




window.onmessage = function (event) {
    let message = event.data;
    if(message.Procedure ==="guiUserUpdate"){
        window.guiOwner = Object.assign(window.guiOwner,message.guiOwner);
        cameraFocus.x = window.guiOwner.transform.x;
        cameraFocus.y = window.guiOwner.transform.y;

    }else if(message.Procedure ==="sendObjectsToRender"){
        //for auto scaling the canvas
        canvasCtx.canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
        canvasCtx.canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
        // Clear the whole context and reset the canvas
        canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, ( canvasCtx.canvas.width )/ 2, ( canvasCtx.canvas.height) / 2);
        canvasCtx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        // Scroll the canvas so that the middle of the screen is the coordinate origin
        canvasCtx.translate(( canvasCtx.canvas.width )/ 2 , ( canvasCtx.canvas.height) / 2 );
        // And scroll it so that the camera focus is in the middle
        canvasCtx.translate(-cameraFocus.x * window.renderScale,
            cameraFocus.y * window.renderScale);
        drawBackground(canvasCtx,window.renderScale,window.imageArray,window.imageIndexArray,window.mapWidth,window.mapHeight);
        let array = message.gameObjects;
        for (let i =0;i<array.length;i++){
            objectPool[i]= array[i];
            renderGameObject(objectPool[i])
        }


        // For Click evt TODO: Make sep-function for these
    }else if(message.Procedure ==="buildGameObjectClickBox"){
        let gameObject = message.gameObject;
        if(clickBox.objectType!== undefined){
            GUI.removeChild(clickBox.objectType);
        }

        buildGameObjectClickBox(clickBox,window.guiOwner,gameObject,0,500,500,500)
    }else if(message.Procedure==="buildPlanetClickBox"){
        let gameObject = message.gameObject;
        if(clickBox.planettype!== undefined){
            GUI.removeChild(clickBox.planettype);
        }
        buildPlanetClickBox(clickBox,window.guiOwner,gameObject,500,1200,500,500)
    }
};







    function renderGameObject(gameObject) {
        let pIndex = gameObject.texture.index;
        let img = imageIndexArray[pIndex];
        let x = gameObject.transform.x * window.renderScale;
        let y = -(gameObject.transform.y * window.renderScale);
        let rotation = Math.radians(gameObject.transform.rotation);
        let width = gameObject.transform.width;
        width *= window.renderScale;
        let height = gameObject.texture.height;
        height *= window.renderScale;
        // Render the gameObject
        canvasCtx.translate(x, y);
        canvasCtx.rotate(rotation);
        canvasCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width / window.renderScale, height / window.renderScale,  // Make sure the image is not cropped
            -width/2 ,         // X
            -height/2 ,        // Y
            width, height);     // width and height
        canvasCtx.rotate(-rotation);
        canvasCtx.translate(-x, -y);
        // Render all of its children
        for (let childKey in gameObject.fixedGameObjects) {
            renderGameObject(gameObject.fixedGameObjects[childKey]);
        }
    }
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Problem:  To be completely clear, the problem I am having is that the garbage collector is working overtime and deleting all the objects whereas I want to reuse them. This is not a post message choking the pipe problem it works fine, but every few seconds our good olegarbage man takes up your driveway for 10 hours to remove your day-old groceries.

What I've Tried:  I've tried attaching an array to reference the new array that comes in globally, but it might be that I have to reference the individual objects. I tried to for through all the objects in the list and append them to a global array then use that global array to render the objects(to show they are still in use), this however still results in utter disappointment.

Notes: 
If you are to reference me in using an array buffer, I will have you know that I require to send these objects to multiple child threads. If that is possible using an array buffer, I would like to know how it is done(in detail) as I and the majority of the web do not know how to use array buffers as the information provided is limited and uses an entirely different structure than simply creating an array and sending it.

the code on the main thread is just a for loop that collects objects in the range of a "main object"/guiOwner and then sends those objects to the window after the loop in an array, then deletes the array when they are sent.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a garbage collector problem. Garbage collection has no directly JavaScript-observable effects.

Comment: I did a performance test on chrome tools , it shows massive gc operation on page

Comment: here is the perf test https://imgur.com/a/fi8y3u1

Comment: also here is the proof it is the child and not the main , everything you see there in that html i posted is all the code i am using for the child and all of the included scripts are on/and being used on the main thread . https://imgur.com/a/faOk9L2

Comment: I'm with @static660 - I have seen GC taking massive amounts of time to complete. In one case there was some code churning tons of objects so not only would GC take noticeable time (~1s) when it runs, it ran often (~5 times).

Comment: Just fyi, javascript is single threaded. It performs asynchronous tasks as coroutines at the end of the main process. This excessive garbage collection is most likely caused by you re-declaring/re-initialising the variables, making the old value redundant, and thus getting marked for gc.

Comment: @Sam Judge  I did explain this in my notes